# Find the LAST blank cell (column) and last non-blank row to enter the NOW() formula

Tags: excel, vba

i am really new at VBA and would really appreciate your tips and guidance on this problem.

i would like to be able to enter the NOW() formula, programmatically in the LAST BLANK CELL (column) beside the LAST NON-BLANK CELL-yellow cell in the table image attached. hopefully, the image helps if my question is confusing.

[image]

Comment: Your yellow cell doesn't seem to be beside a non-blank cell?

Comment: Do you mean "in the first blank column, on the last non-blank row"? Also, what code have you created so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Sub Now_formula()

Dim lastR, lastC As Integer
lastR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
lastC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Cells(lastR, lastC + 1).Formula = "=NOW()"
Cells(lastR, lastC + 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow

End Sub
```

Comment: this works exactly how i needed it to work! thank you,@Kwan for the assist to a newbie! :)